# Displaying notification at a specific time in electronjs

Tags: node.js, electron

Good day all, I would like to ask if there is a way for me to schedule a notification in electronjs application? I've tried to search online but didn't find any clue on how to do it. Any info or suggestion is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

So after googling more, I found out that I can keep the application alive by creating a [window tray](https://gist.github.com/bellbind/f65f78a35bbbd4917a8ae4a6b18c5012) and hide the app window. So I decided to hide my app while using [node-schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule) to schedule a notification whenever a task is scheduled and [node-notifier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-notifier) to create the notification pop-up. I'm not sure if this is an appropriate way of doing it. If anyone has a better solution for this, I'm all ears.